# Representing a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ as sum of only two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible?
Or more generally can any vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ can be represented as sum of (n-1) or less vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

-----EDIT-----

What I basically want to ask is that can *only* two vectors in R^3 form the basis of R^3?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Any vector in any vector space can be written as the sum of $n$ vectors where $n\geq1$.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something like the [dimension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces)

Comment: @Archaick I have added an EDIT in the question.

Comment: Much clearer, thank you. See Omnomnomnom's above comment for your answer. (The answer is 'no'.)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no.

In more detail:  If you choose any two vectors in $\mathbb R^3$, the set of all linear combinations that can be built out of those two vectors will be at most a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.  If you want to get all of $\mathbb R^3$ then you need three linearly independent vectors.

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ there are sets of $n$ vectors such that any other vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be expressed as a linear combination of vectors in the set. The dimension theorem cited in the comment, states that all such sets, called basis, have exactly $n$ elements. If we have a set with only $n-1$ then there is certainly a vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$  that is orthogonal to all the $n-1$ vectors and can not be expressed as linear combination of them.

Answer (score 0):

Nope! That's where the idea of a dimension comes in to linear algebra. $\mathbb{R}^3$ has dimension 3, meaning you need 3 vectors to form a basis. You can form a 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with 2 vectors, provided they are linearly independent, and it will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (meaning it will essentially just be a tilted plane).